# word order in case of a compound predicate

Tags: word-order

So here is a sentence of my own making:

> Wenn ich nur dastehen und sagen "Ich hab' ein stabiles Einkommen" könnte.

Grammar checker permutes it into the following:

> Wenn ich nur dastehen und sagen könnte: "Ich hab' ein stabiles Einkommen.

Is my version of the word order incorrect and if so, why? Am I violating any of the rules here?

Comment: "sagen können" is one verb and does not separate. Thus it either goes before or after your quoted sentence.

Answer (score 6):

We have verb-last order here. In this case, the finite and infinite verb parts can either be placed at the end:

> Wenn ich nur dastehen und "Ich hab' ein stabiles Einkommen"  sagen könnte.

Or, more common, the quote appears after both verb parts:

> Wenn ich nur dastehen und sagen könnte: "Ich hab' ein stabiles Einkommen".

But the parts of the compound verb must stay together. In verb-last clauses, it is ungrammatical to separate them.